# Selecting a Default Option on Load for a .NET MVC Grid

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, nonfactors-mvc-grid

I'm working on an MVC application in .NET 4.5.2 that uses the NonFactors MVC5 grid. Here's a website with the documentation: https://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/

I am running into an issue while trying to adjust the filter for one of my columns. My column contains a boolean type called Status, which either indicates an active or disactive status. When opening the grid, I want to default the filter to only display rows with an active status. The user then would have the option to change the filter to remove the default filtering, or select disactive statuses. I am finding this challenging to do in NonFactors and am hoping that someone would have some suggestions about what to do. The grid object in C# has some filtering methods attached, but does not appear to have any sort of default filter. Additionally, there is a javascript file associated with it that builds the filters but I again do not see any methods that would allow default filtering.

Hopefully someone here is familiar with MVC5 grids (specifically NonFactors) and would be able to provide some assistance. Thank you!

I tried adding the filter through .NET but cannot find any options that are available for defaulting the filter option upon load. I tried modifying the filter through the grid JS file but could not figure out if it is possible. My last option which I did not yet try would be to manually select the filter after loading the grid.